# Hack attempt Windows Server 2019

Tags: vps, hosting, hacking, windows-server-2019, iis-10

I have a Windows Server 2019 VPS for hosting websites. It has all the latest updates. But somehow there is a (partial) hacking attempt. I first noticed it by the SMS I got for high CPU usage of the Microsoft Register Server (regsvr32.exe). With the help of [this site](https://www.techcrises.com/windows-10/microsoft-register-server-regsvr32-exe/) and [Process Explores](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) that the cause was a DLL in the `ProgramDAta` folder.

There I found a zip with the name `set.zip`. Containing the following 5 files. `comhij.dll`, `let.exe`, `rn.bat`, `x.mof` and `xg.dll`. Is seems that the .bat file got executed and was running the script. But it failed somehow, maybe Windows Defender or something else was blocking it causing the high CPU. I know this because the last lines in the .bat causes it to delete itself. And I could not find any of the changes the script wanted to make.

I copied the zip to my own PC, and Norton 360 immediately identified the let.exe as Hacktool, the comhij.dll as Trojan Horse and xg.dll as Trojan.Get.MTB.

The Server has the Windows Firewall active and at the provider level [TransIP](https://www.transip.nl/) there is also a Firewall active.

I was able to find out that the `set.zip` was created by one of the AppPools (hosting a [DotNetNuke CMS](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/) if that matters) with no FTP access.

So my question is how to find out how this happened and how I can prevent it in the future? And how an AppPool can write a file to disk outside it's root directory?
On request I could post the entire .bat script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- How this happened?
  Your web site (whatever contents it runs) was hacked, someone used it to upload and run a trojan to your server. ***How*** exactly it was hacked depends on the site itself, could be a bug, a vulnerability, a too-simple password... anything, really.
- How an AppPool can write a file to disk outside its root directory?
  This depends on the user account the app pool is running as and on file system permissions. Also, even if the user account doesn't actually have permissions to write files where it did, privilege escalation could have been involved.
- How I can prevent it in the future?
  Apart from tightening your security, be wary of bugs or vulnerabilities in your web site; if you are running a web app created by someone else, make sure to check their known vulnerabilities and apply *their* updates too.